# Riemannian Distance function taylor series

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Given a Riemannian manifold $ (M,g) $, in a neighborhood of a fixed point $ x $, the distance function $ d^2(x,\cdot) $ is smooth. In coordinates, the taylor series starts off like:
$$
d^2(x,y) = g_{ij} (x-y)^i (x-y)^j + c_{ijk} (x-y)^i (x-y)^j (x-y)^k + \cdots
$$
What are the $ c_{ijk} $? I am pretty sure they are related to the curvature, but I haven't been able to find a quick answer.

Comment: Surely the $d^{\color{red}2}$ should mean that the odd-order terms vanish. I'd expect some curvature to show up in the fourth-order terms.

Comment: Hi ted, that's not true because d itself is not smooth. For example $ \sqrt{x+x^2} $.

Comment: Well, I admit I was thinking about normal coordinates. Riemann thought about this, but more in terms of the metric tensor itself.

Comment: I think you will not get any clean formula for $c_{ijk}$ without choosing a nice coordinate system (normal). Indeed, on the interval $(-1/3,1/3)$ with metric $(1+2x)^2\,dx^2$ we have $d^2(0,x)=(x+x^2)^2=x^2+2x^3+x^4$. Here $c=2$ has no relation to curvature -- after all, the manifold is isometric to a line segment.

Comment: Actually by symmetry you should have $c_{ijk} = 0$. The next order term is the fourth-order one.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the fourth-order terms ... though.